# Correct pattern for passing data to component from route - Vue Router 4, Vue 3

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vue-router

I have a route where I'm trying to validate that a product exists by checking if it's present in the `products` array before the user enters that URL, if the product doesn't exists they should be redirected to a 404 page.

Sample from: src\router\index.ts

```js
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from "vue-router";
import { products } from "@/products";

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(import.meta.env.BASE_URL),
  routes: [
    {
      path: "/product/:productId",
      name: "product",
      props: true,
      component: () => import("@/views/ProductView.vue"),
      beforeEnter(to){
        const productId = to.params.productId;
        const product = products.find(element => element.id === productId);

        if(!product){
          return {
            name: "404"
          }
        }

        to.params.product = product;

      },

    },
    {
      path: '/not-found',
      name: '404',
      component: () => import("@/views/404Error.vue"),
    },
  ]
});

export default router;
```

By setting `to.params.product = product;` I can access `product` in my `ProductView` component. But this doesn't feel right. Is this the right pattern?

Are there other ways to pass data from a route to a component?

How can I improve this code? Still learning typescript & vue

Comment: you could have `ProductView.vue` get the product Id from `route.params.productId` and then use  `products.find(element => element.id === productId);` again - it does seem repetitive though

Comment: @Bravo Thanks for the response. Yes, it seems a bit repetitive. If this was a request to a back end server I would be duplicating those requests, that's what I'm trying to avoid. Because the route needs to check if the id exists, seems weird to duplicate the requests if I already have the data.

Comment: I would check the validity of the `productId` in `ProductView` and either display in that route something to indicate that the productID is invalid, or, redirect to 404 from ProductView if the productid is invalid - I avoid validation in routes as much as possible - may not be a viable alternative for you though

Comment: @Bravo Thank you, that could work, I'll give it a shot. On a note: maybe I'm biased by Laravel's structure, where before rendering the view, you add logic for validation in the controller. It makes sense not to add too much logic to the routes file for Vue, as in the long run it could get bloated.

Comment: "bloat" is why I avoid validation of this kind in routes - I ended up having a routes which imported all sorts of things. I decided that for my use case, it made more sense not to do that - I wouldn't say one way is better than another though